# How can I enable touchpad settings in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, touchpad

I am using a Bluetooth keyboard with a touchpad for my windows tablet bought from amazon. It is found here:https://www.amazon.ca/Rii-Ultra-Slim-Bluetooth-Multi-touch-Rechargeable/dp/B071Z2YJ33/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1499970580&sr=8-1&keywords=rii+bt11

The problem is that this keyboard comes with a bunch of gestures activated which makes it extremely annoying to use because almost any swipe I make activates a feature and there are no way to disable them because I cannot find the touchpad settings.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel, then in the search, just type in touch. There is a selection under that called "Tablet PC Settings".

Comment: That does not help at all, I'm talking about a touchpad...